# compact but not b-compact set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> B is a b-open set if $B\subset Cl(IntB) \cup Int(ClB)$

I am looking for a set in some topology that is compact but not b-compact. Open sets are b-compact so b-compactness (cover by b-open sets has finite subcover) implies compact.

I guess in metric spaces both definitions coincide so I need to look either in some space that is not even T1, or to be honest nothing is striking me head about this.

I might not be correct about what implies what, I just am not topology guy so please understand if it is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider any infinite set $X$, fix $x_0\in X$ and consider topology $\{\emptyset,\{x_0\},X\}$ on $X$. First of all $X$ itself is compact, simply because it has finitely many open subsets.

But $X$ is not b-compact. Note that if $A\subsetneq X$ is such that $x_0\in A$ then $int(A)=\{x_0\}$ while $cl(\{x_0\})=X$. Which means that $A$ is b-open. Now pick any sequence of different points $(a_i)\subseteq X$, different from $x_0$ (which exists since $X$ is infinite) and define $A_0=X\backslash(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\{a_i\})$, $A_i=\{x_0,a_i\}$ for $i\geq 1$. Each $A_i$ contains $x_0$ and thus is b-open. Moreover those subsets form a cover that has no finite subcover.